# ShGetFolderPath wchar_t won't compile for x64

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013

This compiles fine for x86:

```
wchar_t localAppData[MAX_PATH]; // Array, not a pointer.
SHGetFolderPath(NULL,CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA, 0, NULL, localAppData);
std::wstringstream ss;
ss << localAppData;
return ss;
```

And this compiles fine for x64:

```
char localAppData[MAX_PATH]; // Array, not a pointer.
SHGetFolderPath(NULL,CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA, 0, NULL, localAppData);
std::wstringstream ss;
ss << localAppData;
return ss;
```

However, I would like to find a solution that works both for x86 and x64 so that I don't have to switch the declaration of "localAppData" each time I switch the platform.

Does anybody know a solution?

Thank you.

Comment: I doubt the first compiles fine, considering you have two variables with the same name.

Comment: As for your problem, check your `UNICODE` settings, and possibly use `TCHAR` instead of `char` or `wchar_t`. See e.g. [this reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321.aspx) for more information.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I would not recommend `TCHAR`. Not unless the asker needs to support Windows 98.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I haven't been doing Windows development for some time :) What would you recommend instead?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Using the Unicode API exclusively.

Comment: If you want to use Unicode explicitly, call `SHGetFolderPathW`. Doing so is not subject to your project's character set configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your x86 project is configured for Unicode, but your x64 project is configured for multi byte. Ensure that the character set is consistent across all your configurations. Presumably you intend to use Unicode throughout.